# How to set content offset of SwiftUI ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a `ScrollView`, and I'm able to get the height of the keyboard and set the bottom padding of my `ScrollView` following [this tutorial](https://www.vadimbulavin.com/how-to-move-swiftui-view-when-keyboard-covers-text-field/). However, this tutorial is designed to add padding to a `VStack`. When it comes to a `ScrollView`, adding padding to the bottom works, but doesn't make the content appear above the keyboard. Is there a way for me to instead set the content offset inside the StackView?

I know that in iOS 14, TextFields in ScrollViews are automatically scrolled to appear above the keyboard, however, I am using `UITextFields` turned into SwiftUI views using `UIViewRepresentable`, so this doesn't apply to me.

Comment: Why are you using `UITextField`s rather than `TextField`? If it's to do with some styling of the `TextField` for example, that's a different question.

Comment: Yeah it’s because of styling that I need to use UITextFields

Comment: There’s likely a different way to style them, and if not, can fall back to UIKit using SwiftUI-Introspect

Comment: @George Well the styling is to do with increasing the height of Textfields which seems to be impossible. I can add padding but that doesn't actually resize the textfield itself so the clickable area is off. Also I'm using a UITextView since there's no equivalent for iOS 13 in SwiftUI. I'll have to use introspect I think

Comment: If you add to the end of your question the styling that you couldn't achieve in pure SwiftUI with a bit more detail, I may be able to help.